# move circle in canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I want to move circle 300px right and then stop it. I have no idea how can I make it. When i was looking for some tutorials I always saw endless loops. In documentation I read about time intervals, but I don't think that this good idea for this issue. I want make it look pretty nice, so I want make it move every 1px and clear it. I want to make it run slowly.

Here is my code :

```js
var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

var c = canvas.getContext('2d');
c.beginPath();
c.arc(100, 300, 100, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
c.stroke();

for (var i = 0; i < 300; i++) {
  console.log("dasd");
  c.beginPath();
  // c.clearRect(0, 0, window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  c.arc(100 + i, 300, 100, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
  c.stroke();
}
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Basic_animations

Comment: @lexith probably better if you link to english docs!

Comment: Oops! Adjusting

Comment: You *cannot* move it in a nice smooth animated way without 'time intervals' - otherwise, your function for moving it one pixel at a time will just run so fast that you cannot see the animation. @Jamiec provided the correct way to do it: 'requestAnimationFrame' is the perfect solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be using [`requestAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) - and you can read more about [canvas animation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Basic_animations)

```js
var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

var c = canvas.getContext('2d');

var start = null;
function step(timestamp) {
  if (!start) start = timestamp;
  var progress = timestamp - start;
  c.beginPath();
   c.clearRect(0, 0, window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  c.arc(100 + progress, 100, 100, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
  c.stroke();
  if (progress < 300) {
    window.requestAnimationFrame(step);
  }
}

window.requestAnimationFrame(step);
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```